# Wordpress Slug Umlaut

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, slug

I have 2 problems related to each other!

How do I get slugs working for pretty URLs like : ä , ü , ö , â, á, or what ever exists there.

I dont want them to rewrite it! I really want to make it work with that.. The only way I found was an outdated plugin called 123Echt Laut,.. it still works, but I prefer to have something up-to-date, or a php code that makes it work without rewriting it from, for example ä to ae! I want ä to be displayed in the url as ä!

Plus I want to retrieve that slug.. what I found with google was this:

```
?php global $post;
$post_slug=$post->post_name;?>
```

I wanted it to retrieve the word: fünkel
What I got was : f%c3%bcnkel

Comment: Umlaut in URL, reälly?

Comment: @Unheilig - Why not?  http://cira.ca/news/ca-takes-french-accent

Comment: I was just wondering / curious. Normally German Umlauts could be equivalently replaced / represented with adding a -e ending (same as with ß with "ss"), while French accents or Spanish could not, hence (to me) it is justifiable for a URL to have French accents because they are not representable in English as with German Umlauts. Am curious to know how this could be done, as well.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought you were referring to having accents in URLs at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50533/how-to-map-permalinks-with-accented-letters-to-sanitized-slugs) although that one is on WordPress Stack Exchange.  In fact, this question should be posted there as well since it is technically a WordPress question.  That being said, here's the answer posted there which I think is what you are looking for.

```
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes');
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'restore_raw_title', 9, 3 );
function sweURLtoCHAR($text)
{
  $url=array(
    "%C3%84","%C3%A4",
    "%C3%9C","%C3%BC",
    "%C3%96","%C3%B6",
    "%C3%82","%C3%A2",
    "%C3%81","%C3%A1"
  );
  $char=array(
     "Ä","ä",
     "Ü","ü",
     "Ö","ö",
     "Â","â",
     "Á","á"
  );
  $str = str_replace($char,$url,$text);
  $str_new = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
  return strtolower($str_new);
}
function restore_raw_title( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {
  if ( $context == 'save' )
   return sweURLtoCHAR($raw_title);
  else {
   $title_new = str_replace(" ", "", $title);
   return strtolower($title_new);
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Oh, and to get "fünkel" from "f%c3%bcnkel", use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).  And for that matter, come to think of it, you might be able to replace that `sweURLtoCHAR` function with something like this (untested):

```
function sweURLtoCHAR($text)
{
  $str = urldecode($text);
  $str_new = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
  return strtolower($str_new);
}
```